# VBA scrape web data which is contained in Javascript

Tags: javascript, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to get web table data from the following below website and extract the first table regarding Policy rates on the right hand-side.

https://www.researchonline.se/macro/our_forecasts

Have use the following code just to see if it spits out the desired data but keep getting error 91. Suspecting something about Javascript that I need to consider in my code? Below is my code.

```
Dim request As Object
Dim response As String
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Dim website As String
Dim price As Variant

' Website to go to.
website = "https://www.researchonline.se/macro/our_forecasts"

' Create the object that will make the webpage request.
Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

' Where to go and how to go there - probably don't need to change this.
request.Open "GET", website, False

' Get fresh data.
request.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"

' Send the request for the webpage.
request.send

' Get the webpage response data into a variable.
response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)

' Put the webpage into an html object to make data references easier.
html.body.innerHTML = response

' Get the price variable from the specified element on the page and just check in a message box if that is the correct data.

price = html.getElementsByTagName("table")(0).innerText
' Output the price into a message box.
MsgBox price
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
```

The above cannot execute javascript , Though instead of calling url and fetching it from table. you can directly use their API

for example to get policy rate, the site uses API (There are many apis , i have seen by looking into the site). One example is

https://www.researchonline.se/api/MacroAdmin/GetForecast?name=policy&start=Mon%20Sep%2014%202020&end=Tue%20Sep%2014%202021

which will return an xml kindda response, which you can parse with MSXML2.XMLHTTP

Comment: I see, thanks for quick commentary! May I ask how do I call that response page you retrieved above?